# How to create a Time Unit Box?

Tags: tables

I'm pretty new to LaTeX and hence can't seem to figure out how to go about making something similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should help get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{ll}
Shiko &
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{16}{wc{0.25cm}|}}
  \hline
  \textbullet & & & & \textbullet & & \textbullet & & & & \textbullet & & \textbullet & & &  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} \\ \addlinespace
Son & 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{16}{wc{0.25cm}|}}
  \hline
  \textbullet & & &  \textbullet & & & \textbullet & & & & \textbullet & & \textbullet & & &  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. Is there a way to increase the thickness of the dots?

Comment: make your text size bigger with `\large` example, you can put that command in side your tabular.